# base64 encode a JSON for Mixpanel API pixel tracker

Tags: python, mixpanel

According to [Mixpanel doc](https://mixpanel.com/docs/api-documentation/pixel-based-event-tracking), I need to base64 my json array before sending it to their API endpoint

```
json = {"event": "e-mail opened", 
        "properties": {
        "distinct_id": "28224", 
        "token": "494f5d201963457e632d463d1d4745e4", 
        "time": int(time.time()), 
        "campaign": "gameweek 27"
            }
    }
```

Per the doc, I need to send it like that

> http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=[BASE_64_JSON_EVENT]&ip=1&img=1

Here's my python code to convert the dict to base64 and send it. I get

`data = base64.b64encode(json.dumps(json))
url = 'http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=%d&ip=1&img=1'%data
requests.get(url)`

My problem is that it doesn't track anything. If I convert the same dict using [this online converter](http://www.percederberg.net/tools/text_converter.html) and construct the url manually it work.

So there's probably something who's not working in my encoding but what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is a typo in the question, but instead of:

```
url = 'http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=%d&ip=1&img=1'%data
```

it should be

```
url = 'http://api.mixpanel.com/track/?data=%s&ip=1&img=1'%data
```

as the `%d` expects a number, not a string, like `%s` does